# psutil module in python

Tags: python, psutil

I am a newbie in python and trying to get an understanding of `psutil` module. My question is that if have more than 1 instance of a process (e.g. two instances of VLC media player), does `psutil.kill()` kills all the instances of that process or only one of the instances?

Comment: Quite easy to try - what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  `kill` is a method called on a process object, so it is a question of finding the right process.  You might iterate through them:

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
try:
    print("{:4d} {:4d} {:s}".
          format(proc.pid, proc.ppid, proc.exe))
except psutil.AccessDenied:
    pass
except psutil.NoSuchProcess as err:
    print("****",err)
```

The example exception handling is to handle race conditions - the process might finish between finding it and interrogating it.  The issue is identifying the correct process you wish to kill.  Typically you would use the process ID, `pid`, or maybe `cmdline`.  If you do wish to kill all instances, then use `exe`.